# Should parsing JSON be the client's responsibility or server's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, backend

My GET endpoint /charts currently gives back the payload...

{
status: 200,
chart: "[{"":""}]"
}

I've always wondered if I should be "JSON.parsing" it before I send the payload back to the client or not.  What is standard practice?  Chart array can have 100k's of points or maybe just a few.

Maybe it depends on what my client expects, but if so, is there a standard in what a client should expect from an endpoint like this? json string vs an object

Comment: I dont see any problem with this...you are getting a JSON object array back.

Comment: no, you almost never want to send double-encoded JSON over the wire, it's slower and uses more bandwidth to escape all those quotes. You should have a pure object you jsonify just before shipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending off of @dandavis's comment - you should definitely not send doubly-encoded JSON. While not incorrect, it is very misleading for the consumer of the API.

The endpoint should respond with consistent, well-formatted data. 
The `chart` property should be a regular object. Once you've got all of your data ready to send out, do the `JSON.stringify` around that data.